# ShowModalDialog title disappearing after postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, postback, showmodaldialog

this post is similar to another one I posted previously but the suggested answer didn't work :(

I am spawning a new dialog window through showmodaldialog. The title is set in the  tags of the aspx page. When the dialog is created and shown, the title of the dialog box is correctly set. However anytime I do a postback on the page (e.g select a value from a drop down box, select a row in a gridview) the title disappears leaving just --WebPage Dialog.

I have tried to re-set the dialog title using document.title via javascript and also Page.Title via vb.net but no joy. Everytime a postback occurs, the dialog title is lost. This does not happen in any of my other showmodaldialog windows in my application.

The only difference between them and this dialog window is that this is a dialog window opening from within another dialog window (i.e. 2 dialog windows open - the first window, when a link is clicked, it opens this second dialog window where the title disappears upon postback).

Can anyone suggest what the problem is?

Thanks,
C

Comment: Sorry I should add, this problem only occurs on IE6 but doesnt occur on IE8. Unfortunately, we have to support IE6...thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be you might assign the title after the showdialog() method.

you have to set the title before the showdialog()

Comment: When I place the title in the <title></title> tags, it still gets erased whenever a postback occurs on the dialog. Do you mean I have to 'pass' the title in as a dialog arguement in the showmodaldialog method? If so, I am already passing dialog arguemnts (a reference to the parent window to be exact) so how can I pass more than 1 dialog arguement and then set the title correctly? thanks for your help